# Is there any way write representation class inherited from xmlelement for specific xmlelement? (Or what is the best way?)

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I'm tring to write a class which is inherited from xmlelement and this class going to specify a specific node in XML.

XML file like this

```
<Data id="01">
  <Obj class="class1" dist="dist1">
        <parameter name="Measurement">1min</parameter >
        <parameter name="mt">0</parameter >
  </Obj >
  <Obj class="class2" dist="dist2">
        <parameter name="Interval">0</parameter >
        <parameter name="Th">6</parameter >
  </Obj >
</Data>
```

And my representation like this

```
class CDataObject : XmlElement
{
     ...
      protected internal CDataObject(string prefix, string localName = "Obj", string? namespaceURI, XmlDocument doc) : base(prefix, localName, namespaceURI, doc){}
     ...
      public static CDataObject findObject(XmlDocument doc,string objClass, string objDist)
    {
     ...
     return doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode(xpath) as CDataObject;// this is return null
    }  
     ...
}
```

But I could not get directly XmlElement as CDataObject.(For exemple  findObject function) My node name is constant( "Obj" node). Only attribute(class and dist) values mutable. I know, parent class cannot cast to derived class. So I couldn't beat this, is there any advice for me.

PS: I already represent xml file with xmldocument inhetance and I can access, manipulate any node.  But I could not represent specific xmlelement with inheritance.

Comment: The best way ? Don't write your classes around their representation which in your case is XML.

Comment: @aybe Ok many thanks, what should be my approach?

Comment: The object should be POCO with Deserialize and Serialize methods (from/to XML), no need at all to deal with XML in it beside adding attributes to control the serialization. Alternatively, search for xsd.exe tutorials for easier generation.

Comment: @aybe thank you again. I will use this valuable informations in my project. But in my case, I'm only accessible to this configuration xml file with countless variables. Infact My goal is first of manage nodes because when I create or add new node. Client side create physical devices or interfaces. Additionally in other side using raml.xsd.